# Are regular Hausdorff $G_\delta$ spaces normal?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

A [$G_\delta$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_space) is a space in which every closed set is a $G_\delta$ set.  Combining $G_\delta$ space with normal is kind of a strong condition, as it gives the class of perfectly normal spaces.  I am wondering what happens is normal is weakened to regular.

Is there an example of a regular Hausdorff $G_\delta$ space that is not normal?

Or same question for Tychonoff $G_\delta$ spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane) is an example.  It is Tychonoff and closed subsets are $G_\delta$, but it is not normal.

That this space is Tychonoff and not normal is mentioned in the wiki article linked above.  For the fact that it has closed sets $G_\delta$, see this post: [Moore plane / Niemytzki plane and the closed $G_\delta$ subspaces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2711463/moore-plane-niemytzki-plane-and-the-closed-g-delta-subspaces)

Answer (score 2):

The [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) is another example. It has a base of clopen sets, so it is Tikhonov, and it is a well-known example of a non-normal product of normal spaces. Finally, Dan Ma’s Topology Blog has [a proof](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/the-sorgenfrey-plane-is-subnormal/) that it is a $G_\delta$-space.